# Fetcher failure for URL: 'file://dropbear.default'. Unable to fetch URL from any source

Tags: linux, yocto, openssh, dropbear

I am trying to override the dropbear.default

The layer looks like this :
 *meta/recipes-core/dropbear*

```
    ├── dropbear
    │   ├── 0001-urandom-xauth-changes-to-options.h.patch
    │   ├── 0005-dropbear-enable-pam.patch
    │   ├── 0006-dropbear-configuration-file.patch
    │   ├── dropbear
    │   ├── dropbear.default
    │   ├── dropbear-disable-weak-ciphers.patch
    │   ├── dropbearkey.service
    │   ├── dropbear@.service
    │   ├── dropbear.socket
    │   └── init
    ├── dropbear_2020.81.bb
    ├── dropbear_%.bbappend
    ├── dropbear.inc
    └── files
        ├── 0007-patch1.patch
        └── 0008-patch2.patch
    └──$MACHINE folder name
        ├──dropbear.default   -------> this one I want to use to replace the old one from the /dropbear/dropbear.default above
```

I created a  dropbear_%.bbappend

and in that dropbear_%.bbappend file I have

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend_myfolder := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:${THISDIR}/${MACHINE}:${THISDIR}/files:" -----> this should be

${THISDIR}/${MACHINE}:${THISDIR}/files:"

Still I got the same error

Comment: Please edit your commit to have something resembling the output of the `tree` command, we cannot help you with the current content of your post. Also, where is your dropbear_%.bbappend file in that layer (include it in the output of `tree`).
I can already tell you that `_myfolder` should be removed from `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend`.

Comment: hey, thanks for replying, I think I mislead the context, the name of the folder (my folder) is the name of  $MACHINE , if I put any random patches it will work but if I took any fo the service files out of the dropbear folder nothing would work. I don't know if it's because of license checksum related issue

Comment: Your post is unreadable, please edit it. Give relative path to the root of the layer for each file/directory at least. Or use `tree`, or `find`, whatever piece of software. Thanks.

Comment: let me know if you can see it better now

Comment: That's much better, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty unusual to have a bbappend in the same directory as the bb recipe it'll append to, but whatever floats your boat :) In that case, this unusual scenario is actually part of the issue.

I'm unsure what `_myfolder` is representing in `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend_myfolder`? If `myfolder` is not part of the `OVERRIDES` variable (or other implicit values, such as `class-target`, `virtclass-`, etc..) then it'll not work. I'm pretty sure you should actually just strip it from `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend`. c.f. https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-OVERRIDES

Considering the current directory layout, the `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend` in your bbappend will be expanded to:

```
./dropbear:./${MACHINE}:./files:
```

The paths that will be searched by Yocto for files in `SRC_URI` will be searched from leftmost to rightmost, c.f. https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-FILESPATH (it is not phrased clearly though IMO I can give you that).

So technically, you're telling Yocto to search within the `dropbear` directory for `dropbear.default` first and then `${MACHINE}` directory and then `files`. Which is already what's used by the original recipe, so all in all, your bbappend is a no-op for files you want to override.

To fix this, either:

- move your bbappend to another directory (and probably layer since I'm pretty sure you don't have the rights to commit and push to the layer where the original dropbear recipe is? Then the `dropbear.default` file will be taken from `dropbear`, `${MACHINE}` or `files` directory at the same level as your bbappend. (and since the paths in `FILESEXTRAPATHS` (and `FILESPATH`) are absolute, it'll find the file you want),
- remove `${THISDIR}/${PN}` (which is `./dropbear`) from your `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend` or put it after the directory in which you have placed the file you want to override,
- put a subdirectory named after the machine (`${MACHINE}`) directly in `./dropbear` since directories specified in `FILESPATH` (and thus, `FILESEXTRAPATHS`) are automatically extended with `FILESOVERRIDES` which contains the machine name. Basically, let's say `FILESPATH` is set to `dirA:dirB`, `dirA/poky` (if poky is your distro) will be searched first, then `dirB/poky`, then `dirA/machine`, `dirB/machine`, `dirA` and finally `dirB`. So by having a subdirectory named after your machine in `./dropbear` it'll be searched before `./dropbear` by Yocto automatically. c.f. https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-FILESPATH

You can check which directories are searched and in which order by reading the `log.do_fetch` log file from `${WORKDIR}/temp`, with `${WORKDIR}` probably going to end with being something like `tmp/work/<target_arch>/dropbear/2020.81-r0/`.

You can check the values of variables and the history of how the values were built by running `bitbake dropbear -e`. Since it can output several millions of lines, you usually either pipe it to `less` or `more`, redirect it to a file or pipe it to `grep -e "^VARTOCHECK="`.

Comment: this is so detailed and dedicated, thank you so much for the response, now I will implement it in a correct way, yes FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend_myfolder is part of the bbappend

Comment: there is a type in my post should be 
${THISDIR}/${MACHINE}:${THISDIR}/files:"